# Can't Access Entries in Code Behind file?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am beginner to Xamarin-forms.

I wrote a simple Code for adding two numbers.
but in Code behind file visual studio don't give entries (x:Name) in the intellisense and when i explicitly type it and convert it to integer and add them together... Emulator says "Uncaught Exception : Specified Cast is Invalid."

> I cleaned my solution alot of times and build it again but the
>   situation still remain the same!

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld"
             x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin-Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Entry x:Name="first_number" Placeholder="Enter First Number" />
        <Entry x:Name="second_number" Placeholder="Enter Second Number" />
        <Button x:Name="btn_click" Text="Add" Clicked="Btn_click_Clicked" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Btn_click_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(first_number);
            int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(second_number);

            int result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            DisplayAlert("On Button Click Event", "Addition of Two Number is  : " + result, "OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The x:Name is for the element (in this case Entry). And no conversion between Entry and int exists. `int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(first_number.Text);` should probably work. That being said I advise you to create a viewmodel for this page, bind properties of your viewmodel to the Text fields of the entries. And to finish create a command for your button (also defined on the viewmodel).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to convert an Entry to Int.

What you want is the entry value, more specifically `first_number.Text;`

So, in your code

```
int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(first_number.Text);
int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(second_number.Text);
```

Comment: i can't get intellisense ? of all elements ? how to get that ?